# ASP.NET MVC - AJAX Postback vs Full post back

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Why not always use AJAX Postback instead of a full postback and pass in the model via JSON since an AJAX Postback is always faster?

Answer (score 1):

Complexity, for the most part.  AJAX pages are more complex, and have more quirks and hoops to jump through.  Many people just don't want to deal with it.

Also, Ajax is not always faster.  It really depends.